# How do I get Tetris Midlet to compile and run?

Tags: java-me

I downloaded the tetris source from http://www.kiang.org/jordan/software/tetrismidlet/ created a project in NetBeans named the resulting project "Tetris" and attempted to go to the project properties, click on application descriptor, click on the MODlets tab, typed in Tetris for the name and TetrisMidlet for the class. TetrisMidlet is now in red and it says "Some MIDlet classes are invalid" on the MIDlets tab. It says it compiles alright but when it runs the emulator it says corrupt jar.

I'm trying to make "Tetris" appear as an option in the phone emulator. How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a mark next to each "package" statement. I clicked on them and it said they were in the wrong directory. I chose the options to move the packages to the proper directory. I then went back to application descriptor, went to the Midlet tab chose tetris.TetrisMidlet and now it works.